# Cannot set home web server for universal access

Tags: port-forwarding, nat

I was trying to set up a home web server for universal access on port 80. I disabled the firewall to and set up port forwarding on the router correctly.

When I tried to reach my server outside of LAN using public IP address but couldn't reach it.

Then I noticed that the public IP shown on google (103.83.**.**) was different from the one I saw on router status page (10.**.**.**).

Someone suggested that I may be sitting behind the CGNAT and it could be the reason for not being able to reach the web server.

Can anybody suggest how to set up a web server if I am facing a situation as above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read [Alternatives to Port Forwarding & NAT](https://portforward.com/help/alt-to-pf.htm): "There are four major problems that you may run into that would require alternatives to port forwarding. " ...

Answer (score 0):

It would appear you are double NATed. 103.83 -WAN-[ISP_GW]-LAN 10.n.n.n-WAN-[router]-LAN.  Both ISP and your own router performing NAT.  You would have to also forward port 80 from ISP WAN to the WAN address of your router.
That said, if this is for legitimate general web use, the whole project is ill advised. You are inviting abuse. Unless you are a security engineer setting up a honey-pot, I hope you will consider using a web hosting provider.

Comment: Please don't take it that way, I'm a beginner just trying to get my head into the things. I just want to learn. So, If a ask for a private public IP for my router from my ISP, would it work(in case ISP doesn't forward 80 for me, its obvious)?

Comment: @SatishTyagi - A "private public ip address" does not exist.  I would concur with the advice that you should be using a web hosting provider.  It is very difficult and time consuming to configure a web server the correct way, so it's not only secure, but runs the required environment you need.

Comment: Setting up you own web host is a great learning project, and there are lots of good use cases for hosting a website on your LAN for LAN users. Making that server publicly available means you also have to keep it secured from Internet threats. Threats are constantly evolving: vulnerabilities discovered every day, requiring prompt patching/mitigation to keep your web host secure. You don't want a compromised server on your local network. So, go ahead and learn hosting with a local service. If you want to host to public, you can buy a web host acct for the same cost as a static IP from your ISP

Comment: I understand that quite correctly, but I still ask just out of curiosity that If somehow I get a public IP address of my own for my router, would I be able to get my work done then. I'm not implementing any web server for real, I'm just finding how to do it

Comment: security aside, you have two hurtles to overcome in order to host a service for Internet users. (a) Double NAT:  if you have both an ISP provided router + your own, both acting as NAT firewall, you want to switch the ISP GW to 'bridge-mode'. It would then stop acting as a firewall and your router would get public-ip on it's WAN interface. (b) Dynamic IP.  While your public-ip could remain the same for months, it's likely to change at some point. There are two solutions (1) static-IP (2) Dynamic DNS. I'd recommend looking into the later.